# adding text file data to Array java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader, copyonwritearraylist

I want to add data from Text.txt file to ArrayList in java.

I had created a POJO Employee class with just getters and setters:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String designation;
    private String joiningDate;

    public Employee(String name, String designation, String joiningDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }

    public String getJoiningDate() {
        return joiningDate;
    }

    public void setJoiningDate(String joiningDate) {
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }
}
```

**And this is my main class :**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<Employee> emplo = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://Test.txt"));

        try {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
                String token[] = line.split("|");
                String name = token[0];
                String designation = token[1];
                String joiningDate = token[2];
                Employee emp = new Employee(name, designation, joiningDate);
                emplo.add(emp);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < emplo.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(emplo.get(i).getName() + " "
                        + emplo.get(i).getDesignation() + " "
                        + emplo.get(i).getJoiningDate());
            }

            file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
```

**Text file data:**

```
John|Smith|23

Rick|Samual|25

Ferry|Scoth|30
```

**What I want:**

```
John Smith 23

Rick Samual 25

Ferry Scoth 30
```

Any help in this will be appreciable

Comment: `line.split("|");` should be `line.split("\\|");` because `String.split` uses a regular expression.

Comment: [*A pipe symbol allows regular expression components to be logically ORed.*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/operator/pipe)

Answer (score 4):

Split method takes **regular expression** as a parameter, **not a plain string**. This will do the job:

```
String token[] = line.split("\\|");
```

Comment: Actually it's a great example of escaping. You have to escape pipe character ('|') with backslash in order for regexp to be correct. Then you have to escape backslash with another backslash in order for string, containing a regexp, to be correct Java string.

Answer (score 2):

Actually split() method takes regular expression as its parameter.
The regular '|' is used as special character to use it as plain character use

```
line.split("\\|");
```

This should do it

All the best

Comment: someone already responded with the same answer, why duplicate? It's even in the comments.

Comment: dint see the comment part and think both posted at almost same time